# Installing libtiff on Windows (Anaconda) doesn't yield working package. Help pls

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pip, conda, libtiff

I have 16-bit data that I want to save to compressed TIFF file using libtiff. I thought it would install the package with (ana)conda and be done with it, but to no avail.
Miniconda finds, downloads and seems to install libtiff 4.0.9, but when trying to import the package it fails to find it.

Using pip (`pip install libtiff`) I get pylibtiff 0.4.2 installed as well, but when trying to use this to import libtiff I get the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>    File "C:\Prog\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\libtiff__init__.py", line 20, in 
>      from .libtiff_ctypes import libtiff, TIFF, TIFF3D
>    File "C:\Prog\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\libtiff\libtiff_ctypes.py", line 46, in 
>      raise ImportError('Failed to find TIFF library. Make sure that libtiff '
>   ImportError: Failed to find TIFF library. Make sure that libtiff is installed >and its location is listed in PATH|LD_LIBRARY_PATH|..

There are binaries installed to my \pkgs directory in miniconda, but these are apparently not found by my python environment, even when adding the .dll directory (`\Miniconda3\pkgs\libtiff-4.0.9-hb8ad9f9_1\Library\bin`) to the system path.

How does one fix this? I tried to download Libtiff source code and to build it under Windows (using cmake and Visual Studio -- unsuccessfully, as my C-building skills are very elementary).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, to solve the problem at hand libtiff is not required -- scikit-image is sufficient. To make things less-than-super-obvious, the default skimage.io.imsave() method seems to prefer working through PIL (note that an exception is made for TIFF). Here it gets a bit tricky, as PIL's support for compressed TIFF files is either flaky, or requires libtiff.

> By default, the different plugins are tried (starting with the Python
>   Imaging Library) until a suitable candidate is found.  If not given
>   and fname is a tiff file, the tifffile plugin will be used.

and

> "Beginning in version 5.0.0, Pillow requires libtiff to read or write
>   compressed files. Prior to that release, Pillow had buggy support for
>   reading Packbits, LZW and JPEG compressed TIFFs without using
>   libtiff."

Secondly, if you have to use libtiff don't try and mix the *conda* and *pip* packages. They seem to have in my case downloaded different and incompatible versions of the package. [The conda package installs the libtiff binaries, but not a python wrapper for it. Hence, importing libtiff (as suggested by some online documentation) does not work even though the libraries are present]

But back to the solution:

Scikit-image, however, comes with an external tool that saves TIFF files (using ZIP or LZMA compression): skimage.external.tifffile.imsave() -- see http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.external.tifffile.html

In conclusion: armed with scikit-image, you can save losslessly Zip-compressed 16-bit TIFF files using the following command (shown here with medium Zip-algorithm compression):

```
skimage.external.tifffile.imsave("Compressed.tif", image, compress=5)
```

Comment: The `tifffile` module does not use the `libtiff` library. Tifffile's zip de/compression uses Python's built-in zlib module.

Comment: The recommended API for saving TIFFs is: `io.imsave('/tmp/compressed.tiff', image, plugin='tifffile', compress=5)`.  The `tifffile` plugin should be used by default for `TIFFs`, so you can also get away with `io.imsave('/tmp/compressed.tiff', image, compress=5)`.